# `Cannot automatically write to dynamic config at: app.config.ts` error during `eas build` of react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am doing a `eas build` of react-native app made with expo. Getting this error

> ☁  react-native-news-app [main] ⚡  eas build
> ★ eas-cli@3.10.2 is now available.
> To upgrade, run npm install -g eas-cli.
> Proceeding with outdated version.
>
> ```
> ✔ Select platform › All
> EAS project not configured.
> ✔ Existing EAS project found for @chimiwangchukwangdi/news-app (id = 70297aaf-289f-4e8b-bcb2-fa1b7e866003). Configure this project? … yes
>
> Warning: Your project uses dynamic app configuration, and the EAS project ID can't automatically be added to it.
> https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/#dynamic-configuration-with-appconfigjs
>
> To complete the setup process, set "extra.eas.projectId" in your app.config.ts or app.json:
>
> {
>   "expo": {
>     "extra": {
>       "eas": {
>         "projectId": "70297aaf-289f-4e8b-bcb2-fa1b7e866003"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> ✖ Linking local project to EAS project 70297aaf-289f-4e8b-bcb2-fa1b7e866003
> Cannot automatically write to dynamic config at: app.config.ts
>     Error: build command failed.
> ```

Not able to build.

I tried setting up the set "extra.eas.projectId" in my app.json and then again running the command `eas build` but it fails again giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had been adding "extra.eas.projectId" to my `app.json` file but the error didnt resolve. So I tried adding the "extra.eas.projectId" to the `app.config.ts` file and the error was resolved.

I am not sure why and how it worked. Maybe someone can comment on it.

You also need to add your `"android.package"` and `"ios.bundleIdentifier"` if your building for ios in your `app.config.ts` file like this:

```js
import "dotenv/config"; 

export default {   
extra: {
    BASE_API_URL: process.env.BASE_API_URL,
    BASE_API_PUSH_URL: process.env.BASE_API_PUSH_URL,
    API_KEY_NEWSAPI: process.env.API_KEY_NEWSAPI,
    API_KEY_NEWSDATA: process.env.PI_KEY_NEWSDATA,
    eas: {
      projectId: "70297aaf-289f-4e8b-bcb2-fa1b7e866003",
    },   },   android: {
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    package: "example.expo.googlesignin",
    googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",   },   ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
    bundleIdentifier: "example.expo.googlesignin",
    config: {
      googleSignIn: {
        reservedClientId: "<YOUR_REVERSED_IOS_CLIENT_ID>",
      },
    },
    googleServicesFile: "./GoogleService-Info.plist",   
}, 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, putting `projectid` within `app.json` worked only when I put it at a higher position with the file but not at the bottom, like this:

[image]